# How to inherit focus with android:duplicateParentState?

Tags: android

I have a complex button which is made up of some layouts and Imagebuttons and then wrapped inside a Relativelayout for ease of use. The individual components work fine- I focus or click on one of the contained imagebuttons and it lights up as expected (drawable state list defines focus & click states).

Now I want this complex layout to behave as a unified button. I set

```
android:clickable="true" and android:focusable="true"
```

in the top-level layout. In all the sub-components I set

```
android:duplicateParentState="true" android:clickable="false" android:focusable="false".
```

With this I get the expected behavior for touch cases- I touch the layout anywhere and all the contained components light up. However, focus does not work. Rolling the trackball now completely ignores the complex button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you've done everything right with `android:clicable` and `android:focusable` flags. This logic should work. Try to explicitly declare the order of focus selection with `android:nextFocus` options.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a custom widget instead of the ImageButton and with that the behavior was as expected.